# C_INCLUDE_PATH equivalent for Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is there a Fortran equivalent to the standard environment variables `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: We certainly do not think Fortran would be dead. Who told you that? Anyway, this is compiler specific. What is your compiler?

Comment: I use several different Fortran compilers regularly. Gfortran in general for most stuff, PGI / NVIDIA HPC SDK when I need OpenACC support, Intel Fortran (ifort) when I'm on an Intel-based cluster, LLVM + Flang when I'm on an AMD-based cluster and they're available there, and IBM XL Fortran when I'm on a POWER-based cluster.

Comment: My statement about Fortran being dead is just to deter contrarians (the C 'master race' people, if they exist, for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gfortran does not use an environment variable to modify the search path for modules.

Much as `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` affect the *preprocessor's* search path, `CPATH` (and `C_INCLUDE_PATH`) can be used when invoking the preprocessor with gfortran.  However, the `use` statement and `include` line are not part of the preprocessing stage: these variables will allow files to be found with `#include` but not otherwise.

The Fortran language more widely does not specify such things. Other compilers beyond the tagged gfortran may use an environment variable of some name in the desired way.

Comment: I see. Do you know if `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPATH_INCLUDE_PATH` is actually a POSIX standard, or is it solely defned in GCC?

Comment: Alternatively, are there other preprocessors other than the GNU preprocessor, which usually comes bundled with GCC (thus present in almost all systems)?

Comment: I believe the origin is GCC rather than POSIX, but those are widely supported by other compilers.  I'm not aware of a compiler suite which supports those but also adds an equivalent for its Fortran compiler. (I tend to add `-I` or equivalent fidelity through the build system rather than rely on environment variables, so it could just be that I've never looked rather than being sure they don't exist.)

Comment: Module searching is simply not a preprocess step, whichever preprocessor would be used. If you want to add to module search path rather than preprocessor include header search path, then you are out of luck.